# Showing NON-Existing Connections!

Tags: connection, mobile-broadband

Yes, it sounds weird. Since 2 days, Ubuntu is showing a **"New Mobile Broadband (GSM) Connection..."**, which **does not exist**. I tried rebooting many times and double checked everything.  **Nothing** is connected to my Laptop.

[image]

Comment: What model computer do you have?

Comment: My laptop : [Compaq 15-s103TX](http://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c04519551)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your laptop has a SIM card inside.  (The HP ProBook does, for instance. Coupled with a data subscription, this is very useful in zones where there is no Wi-Fi.)  You usually find the SIM by removing the battery slot.

Probably Ubuntu detected the SIM after an OS update and is now showing the option on Network Connections.  You can ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for showing interest :) But, I am using my laptop for the past 2 years and I am very much sure that my laptop doesn't have SIM CARD feature.